# Huge database query issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I really need help. My current boss has paid nearly $200k over 2 years ago to get an online order program and the vendor he hired still can't get the program to query quickly enough (within a few seconds).  The file has over 250 million rows and over 300 columns made up of names, addressses and household demographics.  This is sooo frustrating.  I see some people are dealing with huge databases like this so I know there are solutions.  What's worse is that the vendor is frustrated as well and at the point where communication is diffidult. Last they mention is they are using a column based software, but still slow due to all the columns. Please tell me.....  What suggestions can I provide to this vendor?  What are common ways of handling this theses days?   Any advise would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You can tell your boss that if he has paid $200K for such a tool, the vendors better know how to fix it, or demand his money back!

Comment: We will need a lot more info, but step 1 would be don't have 300 fields in a single table.  There's no efficient way to query that since it'll be like a row per page.

Comment: FYI your current question is the equivalent of "I have a car how do I make it run really fast?!?!" with no other information.

Comment: Is data stored on a SQL Server DB (you don't give clear indication of this except for the tag)? If so, looking at the execution plans of the queries, indexes defined, table partitioning, better bandwidth, better hardware or some combination of the above should help alleviate the slowness. Providing more info will get you better, more concrete answers.

Answer (score 5):

> I see some people are dealing with huge databases like this

**No one deals with a huge database like this because - attention - it is not huge. This is like asking for experience with people of powerfull sports-cars... with 50 horse power. Ouch.

350 million rows is "non trivial". It is not large, not very large and definietly not significant on nontrivial hardware.

> The file has over 250 million rows and over 300 columns

Hah? It should have multiple tables (as you say SQL Server, I can assume a relational database and that one having one table is a crime against Coobs theorem).

> What's worse is that the vendor is frustrated as well and at the point where communication is 
>   difficult

Sue for damages?

> Last they mention is they are using a column based software, but still slow due to all the columns.

Sounds like bad design? How can they use column based software **and** SQL Server (which is relational)?

> What suggestions can I provide to this vendor?

That he hires a professional and does not misrepresent his abilities.

> What are common ways of handling this theses days?

You hire a professional. Seriously. The vendor obviously is not prepared for dealing with this amount of data. You waited two years wasting money which means you had no control over your project.

On a decent hardware system you should get sub second queries for an order system like that. Now non trivial hardware may mean your sql server is woefully inadequate and that this is not really a vendor problem but one of using a desktop as hardware. I have a personal 800gb database and it runs on 8 discs for the data and 2 for the logs - OS etc. is separate. And I am still not satisfied with the IO power.

Or you have a case of incompetent programmer on the vendor side.

Comment: Please use a browser that puts the squiggly red line under misspelled words.  That is a good response, but it is really hard to read due to spelling errors.

Comment: There are so many spelling errors in this answer that it hurts to read it, and it seems distinctly unlike your other answers. Did your account get hacked? Did you spill something on your keyboard? Are you answering while on a roller coaster?

Comment: We are ready to sue the vendor.  My boss totally mismanaged this due to just trusting the vendor (company) can do their job.  They were given no hardware or software restrictions.  It's hard for me stepping in now because suggesting to start over or pay someone without being certain they can help is not viable.  I'm trying to read the ruby code (which I never looked at before) and also squeeze info from the vendor.  It's ugly.  It is comforting to know that it should not be a problem though -thank you!!

Comment: More like answering in a bad day... ;) Sorry. Don't feel like correcting it now (I have problems concentrating at the moment), if anyone wants to step in it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you might do is experiment with the data if you have access to it. Rolling something like that into MySQL, Postgres or SQL Server Express is not difficult if you're patient and have enough disk space to handle it.

When you see databases that consist of many, many columns of information there's usually a reason for this. Ideally the table is "de-normalized" that way for performance reasons, but sadly the most common case is a lack of experience on the part of the implementor.

Generally there's a healthy balance between normalization and de-normalization, where data is de-normalized only because of reasonable performance concerns. Too much or too little of this causes trouble for developers.

Showing your boss that you can get results from the same data-set in a fraction of the time would go a long way towards proving your vendor has no idea what they're doing, or conversely, if you have a hard time, maybe the vendor is doing their job but the approach they're taking needs non-trivial improvement.